# xcode 6 is not showing views in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

xcode is not showing views in storyboard. I have xcode 6 beta 2. [image: Note the greyed labels, imageviews and table views]

Comment: It's beta so sometimes thing do not work correctly, also beta 2 is old and you should update to new beta 6.

Comment: can I suggest you use beta 5 as 6 looks quite fragile in comparison.

Comment: Beta 6 is the latest and you should be using it. There's virtually no point in asking for help with obsolete betas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Auto layout and size classes were enabled. I unchecked them in file inspector. And views were visible on storyboard. But this messed up layout. So careful with enabling and disabling auto layout.

Comment: Only unchecking size classes will do. Unchecking size classes and re-checking size classes will preserve the constraints so you can just "Update Frames" and everything will be fine again. There're keyboard shortcuts for "Update Frames" too, handy.